# What AAD error codes indicate consent should be prompted for?

Tags: azure-active-directory, adal.js

I am using adal.js in a SPA client to login and acquire access tokens for my web service. We are updating our app registrations with new permissions, which will require users to consent again.

I'm wondering what set of error codes from AAD indicate consent should be asked for as opposed to taking some other error handling action?

To my surprise, I was unable to Google a full reference listing all error codes AAD may return. Is this information publicly documented? I'm referring to the error codes of the pattern, `AADSTSxxxxx` (i.e. `AADSTS65001`, etc), which may be returned from the `oauth2/authorize` endpoint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`AADSTS65001` is the primary consent error that indicates the end user needs to do consent again. I would recommend against looking for specific AADSTSxxxxxx errors and having your app branch off encountering that error.  Sometimes these change and there could be new errors in the future that indicate a similar "consent needed" message.

If you're building a single-tenant app, a good option is to perform admin consent when you make a required resource update to your app. You can do this by clicking `Grant Permissions` in the Azure Portal or sending an Auth request with `prompt=admin_consent` and signing in with an admin account.

For multi-tenant, there's a few options depending on the app.  One option is to build an admin consent experience for updates like this where an admin could go, hit a button that initiates an admin consent request, and then have the admin sign in.

One new feature coming to adal.js that I believe will make the development process a bit easier is the new interactive acquire token call.  This will allow you to specify a resource on an `acquireToken` call that can show UI and will ask for consent if needed.  Once this is available, your app can attempt the silent `acquireToken` request, and upon failure attempt this interactive version. Watch out for this release on [Github](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-js).

Comment: Our app is single-tenant, however, my team does not have admin privileges to `Grant permissions` to all. Just to be clear regarding your first paragraph, I believe you're recommending detecting `AADSTS65001`, but no other specific error code? However, you also state the error codes may change. What's to keep `AADSTS65001` from changing meaning then? It seems like no error code can be trusted if your statement is true. Can you clarify? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, I do not recommend catching any AADSTS error code and branching off the logic.  I was attempting to describe the meaning of this specific code for general understanding.

Comment: I'll add one more bit of detail, if the app is created by a non-admin, then you will get consent for all required resources on a `login()` call.  It's a bit trickier situation if the admin registers the app, but cannot do admin consent.